# How to keep Uniform.js from sorting select elements

Tags: javascript, html, uniform

I'm using Uniform.js to style some selects. They look great, but upon styling Uniform sorts the list according to the value attribute of each option, which isn't desired. How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was not with Uniform.js, but with another part of the application I was using.

[Link to GitHub issue with more info](https://github.com/pixelmatrix/uniform/issues/232)